# What should I call this widget?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rap

I'm working with RAP and want to add something look like this image into my view. But I have no idea to call this thing to search on internet.

[image]

So sorry for unspecific question.

Comment: What is your Widget supposed to do? Or do you want to find out the name of the id of the Extensions view in Eclipse?

Comment: In my application I want to make a view look like "All Extensions". But I don't exactly what is that thing call to search on google.

Comment: What part do you want to copy? Do you want a table like that, or do you want to show extension points in your registry?

Comment: I want a view inside another view(All Extensions view inside Extensions view) with a Title and a CoolBar like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picture you show is part of a `FormEditor`.

The top line ('Extensions') is a `FormPage` title.

The 'All Extensions' part is a `SectionPart` containing a filtered tree and button.

All these are part of the `org.eclipse.ui.forms` plugin [Eclipse Forms](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseForms/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a multipage-editor.
You can have a look at the code of the Extensions View by using the Plugin spy (select the View -> `Alt+Shift+F1`) to get the containing plugin and then [import the plugin into your workspace](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html).
Or you can try to work yourself into using a framework like [Sapphire](http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/). Take a look at their page. The example looks like the editor you are looking for.

Comment: That's seem like what I need. Thank you for helping me.